# Не работает скрипт плавной прокрутки

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Не работает скрипт плавной прокрутки к нужному элементу на странице, вместо плавной прокрутки при нажатии на кнопку, срабатывает мометальная прокрутка, и меня перенаправляет на элемент, id которого я указал. Код внизу

```
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#menu").on("click", "a", function(event) {
                //отменяем стандартную обработку нажатия по ссылке
                event.preventDefault();
                //забираем идентификатор бока с атрибута href
                var id  = $(this).attr('href'),
                    // узнаем высоту от начала страницы до блока 
                    // на который ссылается якорь
                    top = $(id).offset().top;
                //анимируем переход на расстояние - top за 1500 мс
                $('body,html').animate({
                    scrollTop: top
                }, 1500);
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все работает, проблема на вашем сайте

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#menu").on("click", "a", function(event) {
    //отменяем стандартную обработку нажатия по ссылке
    event.preventDefault();
    //забираем идентификатор бока с атрибута href
    var id = $(this).attr('href'),
      //узнаем высоту от начала страницы до блока на который ссылается якорь
      top = $(id).offset().top;
    //анимируем переход на расстояние - top за 1500 мс
    $('body,html').animate({
      scrollTop: top
    }, 1500);
  });
});
```

```css
#menu {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

section {
  height: 400px;
  border-bottom: 100px solid green;
  /*font-size: 100px;
color: green;*/
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav id="menu">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#ex1">Link #1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#ex2">Link #2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#ex3">Link #3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#ex4">Link #4</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>


<div id="content">
  <section id="ex1">
    ...
  </section>
  <div class="separator"></div>
  <section id="ex2">
    ...
  </section>
  <div class="separator"></div>
  <section id="ex3">
    ...
  </section>
  <div class="separator"></div>
  <section id="ex4">
    ...
  </section>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

this может ссылаться к `window`. Отлавливайте нажатую ссылку через `event.target`.

```
$(".limit.items > div > a").on("click", (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    let id = $(e.target).attr('href'), top = $(id).offset().top;
    $('body,html').animate({scrollTop: top}, 1500);
});
```